# If someone had a list of all primes, would it be possible for them to factor any integer in polynomial time?

Tags: encryption, rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

For example, if they somehow got a function that would churn out any arbitrary amount of primes in a row. Could they break the RSA problem then?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1020/2454) probably answers your question (with a little thought).

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, yes, it will work. Practically, you will require an extremely very long time and an incredible amount of energy, considering the sizes of the primes  involved in RSA (usually around 1024-bit prime numbers). It is about billion and billions of years and billions and billions times the energy of the whole universe ([RSA: How effective is this keypair-trash attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/rsa-how-effective-is-this-keypair-trash-attack))